# Mongo C++ Client Library Doesn't See My Boost

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, build, client-library

I have downloaded Boost version 1.51, built it, and put it to /usr/local/boost_1_51_0.  I have also downloaded mongo-cxx-driver-v2.4.  Since there is no Makefile, I have to run scons, as this project is using the new python build environment.  When I run scons, it checks for boost_thread-mt and boost_thread, from which both return "no".  Obviously, it is not seeing that I have boost in the /usr/local directory.  Since I am a Make and not a scons person, how do I get the mongodb building process to see my version of boost?

```
routerwc:~/mongo_proj/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly # scons --cpppath=/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/ --libpath=/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... no
routerwc:~/mongo_proj/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly # cat config.log 
file /root/mongo_proj/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly/SConstruct,line 70:
Configure(confdir = .sconf_temp)
scons: Configure: Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt....sconf_temp/conftest_0.cpp <-
|
|
|
|int
|main() {
|  
|return 0;
|}
|
g++ -o .sconf_temp/conftest_0.o -c -O3 -pthread -D_SCONS -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -Ibuild -Ibuild/mongo .sconf_temp/conftest_0.cpp
g++ -o .sconf_temp/conftest_0 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-zdefs -pthread .sconf_temp/conftest_0.o -lboost_thread-mt
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no

scons: Configure: Checking for C++ library boost_thread....sconf_temp/conftest_1.cpp <-
|
|
|
|int
|main() {
|  
|return 0;
|}
|
g++ -o .sconf_temp/conftest_1.o -c -O3 -pthread -D_SCONS -DMONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS -Ibuild -Ibuild/mongo .sconf_temp/conftest_1.cpp
g++ -o .sconf_temp/conftest_1 -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-zdefs -pthread .sconf_temp/conftest_1.o -lboost_thread
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: Configure: no
```

Comment: Have you tried setting cpppath and libpath? For example: scons --cpppath=/usr/include/boost141/ --libpath=/usr/lib64/boost141/

Comment: I have not.  Let me give that a go.

Comment: That is still not working.  Here is my situation...
~/mongo_proj/mongo-cxx-driver-nightly # scons --cpppath=/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/ --libpath=/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C++ library boost_thread-mt... no
Checking for C++ library boost_thread... no
Stops here.

Here is the boost_thread library...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 182042 2013-05-21 07:35 /usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage/lib/libboost_thread.so

So I am still not sure why scons is not seeing my boost libraries.

Comment: The configure step that SCons run should have dropped a config.log file. Can you post the contents of that file somewhere?

Comment: I have added the output above.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I download and extract boost in /usr/include/boost_1_57_0 then I run

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Then in the directory i have the c++ drivers i run

```
sudo scons --extrapath=/usr/include/boost_1_57_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you didnt install the libs, just ran ./b2 rather than ./b2 install

Can you try the following?

`scons --extrapath="/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/,/usr/local/boost_1_51_0/stage"`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem.

In the SCons, the order to test the boost libraries is wrong.

Open the SConstruct file and change the following line:

```
boostLibs = [ "regex", "thread", "system" ]
```

to

```
boostLibs = [ "system", "regex", "thread" ]
```

Cheers,

Comment: I put the previous answer.